# How can I solve the mixed content error in web laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hope you're doing well!

I have a website, made in laravel and I am presenting the mixed content error in some url of my page, and this is affecting my website's functionality because it blocks the ajax or js. Here you can see a video of the issue:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A3xPUw9KMhf_rnn-xJBhw77-d5Z7t-Zw

My website is hosted on the cloudways server if anyone knows how I could solve it, I would appreciate your help.

Thanks
Regards

```
      The htaccess file is this:
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          Options +FollowSymlinks
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.saludvitale.com/$1 [R,L]
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /public/css/$1 [L]
              RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /public/js/$1 [L]
              RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ /public/img/$1 [L]
              RewriteRule ^video/(.*)$ /public/video/$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /public/images/$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^users/(.*)$ /public/users/$1 [L]
            RewriteRule ^banner/(.*)$ /public/banner/$1 [L]
                RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ /public/uploads/$1 [L]
              RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*)$ /public/plugins/$1 [L]
              RewriteRule ^chat-images/(.*)$ /public/chat-images/$1 [L]
              RewriteRule ^fonts/(.*)$ /public/fonts/$1 [L]
              RewriteRule ^favicon.ico /public/favicon.ico [L]
              RewriteRule ^robots.txt /public/robots.txt [L]
          # Go ahead and process files.
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
          RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
      </IfModule>
```

part of me AppServiceProvider

```
          use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
          use Auth;
          use DB;
          use DateTime;

          use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

          class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
          {
              /**
               * Bootstrap any application services.
               *
               * @return void
               */
              public function boot()
              {
           URL::forceScheme('https');
                  view()->composer('*', function($view){
                      if(Auth::check()){
                          $profileData=DB::table("professional_details")
                                              ->select('FreeStatus')
                                              ->where("user_id",Auth::id())
                                              ->get()
                                              ;
          ....
```

Comment: You should post the error log / code here, not a video that most are unlikely to watch.

Comment: You need to include the code that might be causing the problem along with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first set up a redirect for all http requests to go to https using .htaccess then make your APP_URL set to use https `https:// webname.com` check SSL Certificate then `add \URL::forceScheme('https');` to the boot() method of your `AppServiceProvider.`

Let me know if you face any problem

Comment: Apply what you tell me, but it does not work for me, I keep presenting the error, this my htacces and AppServiceProvider 
I loaded it on the top